# How to not promote all Docker tags from dev repo to prod using jfrog cli promote command

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

(I am newbee with respect to Artifactory) I use the JFrog CLI for promoting builds (docker images) from dev repo to prod. When I build I create three tags, one *VERSION*, one *latest* and one with a build ID. When I promote using "`jfrog rt bpr`" command I don't want the build-id tag to be promoted, only *VERSION* and *latest*.

I build Docker images using Gitlab and use the JFrog CLI for pushing images, scanning with x-ray and publishing build info to Artifactory.

My process is that in a Gitlab pipeline I build the docker image with three tags.

Then I deploy it to a dev repository in Artifactory with "`jfrog rt docker-push...`" for all three tags and then publish the build info to Artifactory.

Then I test the Docker image in a test stage in the Gitlab pipline, followed by a xray scan of the build using JFrog cli.

When everything works I want to promote the Docker image to my prod repository in Artifactory using JFrog cli. This however promotes all three tags but I would like to only promote the *VERSION* and *latest* tag and not the third tag which is only used as a "snapshot" tag..

Is this possible using jfrog cli promote command?  Or is there a better way of thinking about the whole process of naming, tagging and promoting images from dev to prod using Artifactory?

```sh
This is the build stage:

# Build docker images
    - > 
      docker build       
      -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:latest
      -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:$VERSION
      -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_ID
      .        
    # Push to Artifactory's dev repo via the virtual repo
    - jfrog rt docker-push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:latest docker-virtual --build-name=$CI_PROJECT_NAME --build-number=$CI_PIPELINE_ID    
    - jfrog rt docker-push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:$VERSION docker-virtual --build-name=$CI_PROJECT_NAME --build-number=$CI_PIPELINE_ID    

    # Collect environment variables
    - jfrog rt build-collect-env $CI_PROJECT_NAME $CI_PIPELINE_ID    

    # Push build info to Artifactory, but exclude sensitive information such as passwords 
    - jfrog rt build-publish --build-url=$CI_PIPELINE_URL --env-exclude="*DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG*;*PASSWORD*;*KEY*" $CI_PROJECT_NAME $CI_PIPELINE_ID


This is the promote stage:

- jfrog rt bpr --status=STABLE --copy=true $CI_PROJECT_NAME $CI_PIPELINE_ID docker-prod-local
```

Comment: What if you try to delete the tag on the target repo, post promotion? something like: `$curl -u<user:password> -X DELETE <ArtifactoryURL>/<Local-Docker-Repo-Name>/<Image-name>/<Tag>` or use jfrog cli's ssh auth --OR possibly apply 2 tags and once promotion is done, then apply 3rd tag on the source repo (from where your artifact is getting promoted from)

Comment: My solution for now is to promote the prod using curl since JFrog CLI does not have the support of promoting only parts of repos.

This is how I do it:


`- jfrog rt curl -d "{\"targetRepo\":\"${G_TEAM_NAME}-docker-prod-local\", \"dockerRepository\":\"${G_TEAM_NAME}/${APP_NAME}\", \"tag\":\"latest\",\"copy\":true}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST api/docker/${G_TEAM_NAME}-docker-dev-local/v2/promote`